# Relationship between an NP-hard problems with the subsets of them?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

I am writing a paper. I have a problem and I want to prove that it is an NP-hard problem. However, for simplicity, I select a subset from my problem to prove that it is an NP-hard problem. Although I think that it is reasonable that if a subset of problem is NP-hard, it result in the problem being NP-hard, but I think writing this sentence in a paper need a reference. I will be thankful if anyone helps and gives me a reference for it.

......................
More explanations : My problem includes *N* boxs, B(1) through B(N). Every box B(i) has a size called t(i) and t(i)<=t(i+1). Now, to prove that my problem is NP-hard, I have considered a subset of my problem  such that there are arbitrary number of boxes with size t(N). And for this subset I have proved that my problem is NP-hard, as a result the problem is NP-hard.

> is this an acceptable assumption?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "I select a subset from my problem"?

Comment: It is very unclear what your problem is, but as you stated it, it doesn't sound like an NP problem to me.  And that a subset of a language is in NPC definitely does not mean anything in particular about the classification of the language.  Maybe if you tell us what the problem is we can help more?

Comment: Your original problem already allows an "arbitrary number of boxes with size t(N)." $\hspace{1.47 in}$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is valid.  For example, every language including every language in NP is a subset of $\Sigma^*$, but $\Sigma^*$ is not NP-hard.

To prove NP hardness, polynomial time reduce an NP complete language such as 3-SAT to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that an arbitrary superset of a NP-complete language will also be NP-complete.  In other words, just because your problem is a special case of an NP-hard problem doesn't necessarily mean your problem is NP-hard; it might be that your special case is much easier than the other cases of the NP-hard problem.  For instance, 2SAT is a special case of 3SAT; 3SAT is NP-complete, but 2SAT is not (believed to be) NP-complete.

However, there are some specific conditions where this kind of inference *is* valid. For example, take Hamiltonian Path ($L_1$) and Longest Path ($L_2$), two NP-complete problems.  Hamiltonian Path is a special case (subset) of Longest Path: we have $L_1 \subseteq L_2$.  But one can say more about the relationship between Hamiltonian Path  and Longest Path: we have $L_1 = L_2 \cap L_3$ where $L_3 \in P$.  From the fact that $L_1$ is NP-complete and $L_2$ is in NP, we can infer that $L_2$ is NP-complete too.

In general if $L_2$ is in $NP$ and $L_3$ is in $P$ and $L_1 = L_2 \cap L_3$ is NP-complete, then $L_2$ is NP-complete.  However, the requirement that $L_3$ be in $P$ is essential; the corresponding statement doesn't hold if you allow $L_3$ to be arbitrary (i.e., if you allow $L_1$ to be an arbitrary subset of $L_2$).

Answer (score 0):

Take any NP complete language, concatenate "0" at the end of each of its words the resulting language is still NP complete...
At the same time it is a subset of the set of all strings that end with "0" (this is different than being a subset of the Kleene closure which is a trivial case)

The set of all strings ending with "0" though is decidable in Polytime.

This serves as an example where the subset is NP complete where as the set which contains it is in P.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I hope the above example is suitable.

Comment: "Even string" was unclear -- I guess you meant strings that are even numbers when interpreted as binary numbers, but it's easier to just say strings that end in "0", so I edited. Hope that's OK.

Comment: It looks like you might have accidentally created two accounts.  You can merge them using [the procedure outlined here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).  Also, in the future it's better to edit your existing answer to improve it rather than posting a new answer with your improved answer (and allowing the old one to remain).  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W Sure... Only that my previous answer got created in a way I could not edit.

Comment: @ARi, OK, got it.  After you merge those two accounts, you will be able to edit answers attributed to the other account, so if it ever happens again in the future, now you'll know how to deal with it.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is worded very awkwardly, but I think what you're asking is "If we have a language $\mathcal L$ and we know there exists $\mathcal L' \subset \mathcal L$ such that $\mathcal L'$ is $NP$-complete, is $\mathcal L$ $NP$-complete as well?"

Certainly. We know there exists an $NP$-complete language $\mathcal R$ that is polynomial-time reducible to $\mathcal L'$, say via the reduction $f : \mathcal R \to \mathcal L'$. Then if we simply extend the codomain to $\mathcal L$, we get the polynomial time reduction $f' : \mathcal R \to \mathcal L$, and by definition $\mathcal L$ is $NP$-complete.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The language $\mathcal{L} = \{0,1\}^*$ is not $NP$-complete (assuming $P\ne NP$), even though it does have $NP$-complete subsets.

Comment: Hmm is this the only counterexample? Because, for example, I've seen arguments where we say that one problem is NP-complete because it has another known NP-complete problem as a subproblem. For example, Longest Path is NP-complete because the special case Hamiltonian Path is.

Comment: The problem with your argument is that the reduction requires $f$ must be such that $x \in R \iff f(x) \in L'$. By just extending the codomain to $L$, you now can only say that $x \in R \longrightarrow f(x) \in L$, but the converse is not necessarily true.  As per the example, $x \in L \longrightarrow f(x) \in \Sigma^*$ doesn't make $\Sigma^*$ $NP$ hard.

Comment: @tAllan Yeah that makes perfect sense, and I should have thought about it more before I answered. But then when is it OK to say that a problem is NP-hard because a special case of it is NP-hard, as in my example? I think where I had it wrong is that when you take a generalization of a problem, you don't only increase the size of the language, but the size of the universe of which the language is a subset.

Comment: To answer your question about when it is OK to say that a problem is NP-hard because it is a special case of another NP-hard problem: The relationship between Hamiltonian Path ($L_1$) and Longest Path ($L_2$) is not just that $L_1 \subseteq L_2$; it is that $L_1 = L_2 \cap L_3$ where $L_3 \in P$.  If $L_2$ is in $NP$ and $L_3$ is in $P$ and $L_2 \cap L_3$ is NP-complete, then $L_2$ is NP-complete.  However, the requirement that $L_3$ be in $P$ is essential.  Or, to put it another way, it is not true that arbitrary supersets of a NP-complete language will also be NP-complete.

Comment: @D.W. Ah thanks for clearing that up for me. I guess I need to be more careful the next time I think about special cases of problems.

Comment: @D.W. I think your comment would make the best answer.

Comment: @D.W. The language $\{0,1\}^*$ isn't **NP**-complete, independent of the **P$\,=\,$NP** question. Since $\{0,1\}^*" has no "no" instances, you can't reduce any other language to it.