# Relationship between an NP-hard problems with the subsets of them (part 2)?

Tags: complexity-theory, proof-techniques, np-hard

I asked two questions about NP-hard problems here [Relationship between an NP-hard problems with the subsets of them?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27662/relationship-between-an-np-hard-problems-with-the-subsets-of-them) and here https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30018/does-this-manner-of-proof-for-being-np-hard-is-true but unfortunately maybe I could not describe my question clearly. Therefore here I will do it.
Assume you have a subset-sum problem and there are two subsets of numbers 1- s`ubset A with Integer numbers, 1 to n`, 2- `subset B with Real numbers, 1 to n.` The problem is finding a subset of numbers that the sum of them is equal to S. `1<S <n.`

If we prove that this problem for the subset A is NP-hard whether can we conclude that the problem for the subset B is also NP-hard? I mean since Integer numbers are a subset of Real numbers then can we conclude the above?

I think this is strongly different with false statement "A subset Q of my language P is NP-hard, ergo P is NP-hard".

Comment: Instead of making a new question every time you come up with a new formulation, you should edit the original question.

Comment: Yeah FrankW, thanks for informing me. But. this question has not still any convincing answer.

Comment: Also, this question has some formatting issues.  Please proofread it. And don't use inline code (\`...\`) for emphasis.

Answer (score 3):

If problem A is NP-hard and problem B is a generalization of problem A, then problem B is also NP-hard. Here *generalization* means that every instance of A is an instance of B, and an instance of A belongs to A iff it belongs to B. (Technically, the concept of *instance* is a convenient fiction, but I hope you know what I mean. )